# $f :[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

$f :[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f(0)=0$, then show that $\sup_{0\leq x\leq 1} |f(x)|^2 \leq \int_{0}^{1}\{f'(t)\}^2 dt$

I can prove by CS inequality that

$$ \left|\,f(x)\,\right| = \left|\,f(x) - f(0)\,\right|= \left|\int_0^x 1 \cdot f'(t) \ dt \right| \leq \sqrt{ \int_0^x 1^2 \ dt } \cdot \sqrt{  \int_0^x |f'(t)|^2 \ dt } \leq \sqrt{ \int_0^1 |f'(t)|^2 \ dt }$$

But not getting the supremum as a bound . help

Comment: Your inequality is true for all $x$...

Comment: Take the supremum of both sides. The RHS is independent of $x$.